# I want to complete the FiveM Lua syntax

Tags: lua, fivem

> This is the part of the string inside the "". I want to know if this is okay.

```
"[[�����������"
```

> I want to put this inside the string "" is redundant, is there any way?

```
"`,6<,futb=!;/2f*:=
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov29T.png)

I want to put the two values above in a TriggerServerEvent("") function that exists in a game called FiveM.

To convert that value to a TriggerServerEvent, it must be created as follows

```
TriggerServerEvent(""`,6<,futb=!;/2f*:=", "[[�����������", ,1573218749406,-1,"T1","Dances")
```

Let me know what's wrong with this syntax

Comment: Doesn't Lua tell you _what's wrong with this syntax_? And what do you mean by _"" is redundant_?

Comment: @Armali <"`,6<,futb=!;/2f*:=> If you include a "" in there, it becomes ""`,6<,futb=!;/2f*:=" as

The leading "" is redundant. Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @user name – What you write may be _grammatically correct_, but not meaningful (to me, at least). When someone asks you what you mean by a phrase (here: _"" is redundant_) you can't explain that by again using the very same phrase. Which meaning do you want to express by _redundant_: superfluous, excessive, repeated, unneeded, extravagant, bountiful, prodigal, abundant, …?

Answer (score 1):

To include a double quote (**"**) within a Lua [string](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html) the character must be escaped. Escaping a character means the character will be treated as part of the string, rather than a Lua instruction. To escape a character place a backslash (**\**) in front of it, like so:

```
local message = "he said \"bye\" and left"
print(message)
--Output would be: he said "bye" and left
```